# How to create an optional object key string in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
declare interface timezoneSyntax {
  region: string;
  en: {
    x: string;
    offset: {
      EST?: number;
      EDT?: number;
      [key: string]: number;
    };
  };
  it: {
   x: string;
  }
}
```

How to make the following object optional and also `en` generic?

```
en: {
    x: string;
    offset: {
      EST?: number;
      EDT?: number;
      [key: string]: number;
    };
  };
```

I have tried to convert `en` to `[key: string]?` But it is showing error. Please advice.

Comment: So `en` can be an object or a string?

Comment: Key for optional object.

Comment: I don't get you. Could you please give an example of the structure you want to describe?

Comment: @JonasWilms Done. Please check my edit.

Comment: You just copied the relevant part out of the interface, while that makes your question clearer (the whole interface was never relevant to the question though), you still haven't provided an example of the structure you want to describe.

Comment: What does "`en` generic" mean? Make the structure of `en` generic of the `en` property name generic?

Comment: `en` can be `it` or any string.

Comment: A use case showing what objects should and should not be assignable to the interface would be very helpful here.  If you want to support exactly one property of "generic" key, then you should make your interface generic (e.g., `type TZS<K extends string> = { region: string } & Record<K, { x: string, offset: ... }>`.  If you want to support an arbitrary number of properties of this type then you still might want a generic because that `region` is going to mess it up.  Without use cases it's hard to say what to do.

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to be optional?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indexes of the form `[key: string]: T` can be considered as being always optional, so no need to specify it with the `?` notation.

However, specifying an index signature like that forces *all* interface properties to have the same `T` type as the key. For example, `region` would result in

> Property 'region' of type 'string' is not assignable to string index type '{ x: string; offset: { ... }; }'

This is because an index signature `[key: string]: T` simply dictates how *all* interface properties should be like. An alternative would be to use `[key: string]: any` but you would loosen up your type safety.

From my understanding, this is not a side effect that you want so you should reconsider the use of index keys in this interface and find a different approach.

**Proposal**

Instead of using a language-specific property name (`en`, `it`, `es`, etc), use the generic `language` as a name. If you also need to know what language you are dealing with, then that should be added to the `language` model as `name`.

You would end up with something like this:

```
declare interface timezoneSyntax {
  region: string;
  language: {
    name: string; // `en`, `it`, `es`, etc
    x: string;
    offset: {
      EST?: number;
      EDT?: number;
      [key: string]: number;
    };
  };
}
```

**Further Reading**

[Indexable Types - Official TypeScript Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types)

[Index Signatures - TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html)

Comment: Offtopic Fun fact: `[key: string]: ISomeInterface` does not actually restrict the string on key.

Answer (score 8):

Indexes of the form `[key: string]: T` can be optional. You can try to use  [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)

```
   interface timezoneSyntax {
       page: Partial<{ [key: string]: number }>;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW, It already becomes optional. But, if you still want to explicitly do that then you can do something like this.

```
declare interface timezoneSyntax {
  region: string;
  en: {
    x: string;
    offset:
      | {
          EST?: number;
          EDT?: number;
          [key: string]: number;
        }
      | {
          EST?: number;
          EDT?: number;
        };
  };
  it: {
    x: string;
  };
}
```